# Trying to output user input with only getchar/putchar

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I have to write a simple calculator in C, that only uses getchar/putchar. I need to echo the user input, and then perform the mathematical operation (only need to use +, /, %, *, and -). Right now, I only care about what I'm doing wrong, as far as storing the values into my input variables. The rest of the program should be fairly easy to do myself.

In my while loop, I tried to be careful with nesting if/else's (mainly for error-checking purposes) only inside my "else if's". I want my loop to ignore spaces, and then assign the number, math operator, and other number into input1, input2, and input3, respectively. Right now, if I input something like "55 * 66", I am returned something like "*0".

Thanks for looking.

*UPDATE (3/22/2014):
I'm getting a little bit closer. My problem right now is that the program will only work when I input one space after each number and operand (i.e. "2 + 4" works, but anything without spaces, or with more than one space, does not). I also didn't quite get how to putchar the numbers to output them. I used printf so I could at least have a working program, in the mean time.
Thanks.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int add(int input1,char operand, int input2);
int subtract(int input1,char operand, int input2);
int mod(int input1,char operand, int input2);
int multiply(int input1,char operand, int input2);
int divide(int input1,char operand, int input2);

int main()
{

    int answer = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int input1 = 0;
    char operand = 0;
    int input2 = 0;
    int function = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter a calculation to be made.\n");

    while (((ch = getchar()) != ' ') && (ch != '\n')){

    if (ch == '-') {
        printf("\nError: no negatives allowed.\n");
    }

    else if (!isdigit(ch)){
    printf("\nError: number not inputted (first number).\n");
    }

    else {
        input1 = (input1 * 10) + (ch - '0');
        }
}

    while (((ch = getchar()) != ' ') && (ch != '\n')){

        switch(ch){

        case '+':
        operand = '+';
        break;

        case '-':
        operand = '-';
        break;

        case '%':
        operand = '%';
        break;

        case '*':
        operand = '*';
        break;

        case '/':
        operand = '/';
        break;

        default:
        printf("Error: input is not one of the allowed operands.");
        break;

        }

    }

    while (((ch = getchar()) != ' ') && (ch != '\n')){


    if (ch == '-') {
        printf("\nError: no negatives allowed.\n");
    }

    else if (!isdigit(ch)){
    printf("\nError: number not inputted (second number).\n");
    }

    else {
        input2 = (input2 * 10) + (ch - '0');
        }
}

printf("%d", input1);
putchar(' ');

printf("%c", operand);
putchar(' ');

printf("%d", input2);

putchar(' ');
putchar('=');
putchar(' ');

if (operand == '+'){
answer = add(input1, operand, input2);
printf("%d", answer);
}
else if (operand == '-'){
answer = subtract(input1, operand, input2);
printf("%d", answer);
}
else if (operand == '%'){
answer = mod(input1, operand, input2);
printf("%d", answer);
}
else if (operand == '*'){
answer = multiply(input1, operand, input2);
printf("%d", answer);
}
else if (operand == '/'){
answer = divide(input1, operand, input2);
printf("%d", answer);
}

    return 0;
}

int add(int input1,char operand, int input2){

return input1 + input2;

}

int subtract(int input1,char operand, int input2){

return input1 - input2;

}

int mod(int input1,char operand, int input2){

return input1 % input2;

}

int multiply(int input1,char operand, int input2){

return input1 * input2;

}

int divide(int input1,char operand, int input2){

return input1/input2;

}
```

Comment: You have two cases that test for `isdigit(ch)`.  The first one does nothing, and will always be taken in favor of the second one which stores `ch` in `input3`.

Comment: You can use `isspace` to check for whitespace.  Also, what are you hoping to accomplish by comparing `ch >= 0` after it has been established that `ch` is a digit?  Don't forget that `ch` is the ASCII value for a digit character, not the numeric value of the number itself.

Comment: `ch >= 0` will not test if the number is greater than or equal to 0. It will test if the encoding for the character entered is >= 0. Not quite what you want. Maybe you meant `ch >= '0'`, but that's not of much use either. Just go with `isdigit()`. Remember that if the user entered a negative number, you will first read a `-`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - Regarding checking whether ch >= 0, part of this code is that I want to check for, and exclude, negative numbers. I should have made that clear. I also added "input1 = ch;" in the first else if, which I'm not sure why it wasn't there. I'm still having issues, though.

Comment: What you have in your hand is the ASCII value of a single digit character, not a signed multi-digit integer.  You are going to have to write a more complicated parser to read an optional '-' followed by multiple digit characters, convert each digit from ASCII to the actual numeric value, and merge them into a single integer in some number base (typically, we use base 10!).

Comment: I think my problem is that when the loop repeats for the second number, after the math operator, it will store it into input1 again. Even though it's not good coding, I tried incrementing a counter after the first digit is read, and then making part of the condition of assigning ch to input3, that the counter had to be == 1, and that it was a digit.

Comment: Do you plan to handle operator precedence?  This is an expression parsing problem, which is typically handled with an operand stack and an operator stack.  The operand stack holds multiple values, in contrast to your `input1`.  If this is an assignment, I would imagine that the teacher gave some instruction on how to go about solving it no?

Comment: You need to start by writing a tokenizer that can convert the stream of characters into a stream of tokens (probably just an integer token, an operator token, and an END token).  Your calculator should work on the stream of tokens, not directly on the stream of characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regarding what you are talking about, he definitely did not give us instructions on that. I have to input a math expression from the user, echo it back and then perform the operation, all with only getchar/putchar (except for error-checking). I might be going about this the wrong way, though.

Comment: Can the numbers be limited to single-digit positive integers?  Do you need to support parentheses and operator precedence?  If you answered yes to the first and no to the second, then the problem is much simpler.

Comment: btw, if you're only allowed to use `getchar()` and `putchar()`, does that mean that you can't use `isdigit()`?  Are you allowed to call `printf()` (because you are)...

Comment: I can use isdigit, and printf for the purposes that I am using them for. Regarding your previous question, I don't need to worry about parenthesis, but I need to account for multiple-digit integers.

Comment: Ahh, and there will only be one operator?  So you don't have to handle `10 + 20 * 30`?

Comment: Correct. I just need two digits, and one of the five allowed math operators for this. I was researching this a bit. Pat, would I need to change the "input1 = ch;" to "input1 = input1 * 10 + (ch - '0');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to parse each piece of the expression in sequence:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    int a;
    char op;
    int b;
    int negate;

    // start with a character of lookahead
    ch = getchar();

    // skip leading spaces
    while (ch != EOF && isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') ch = getchar();

    // read A operand
    a = 0;
    if ((negative = (ch == '-'))) ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF || !isdigit(ch)) {
        // error, expecting a digit or '-' here
    }
    do {
        // convert digit from ASCII, and "shift" into accumulator
        a = (a * 10) + (ch - '0');
        ch = getchar();
    }
    while (ch != EOF && isdigit(ch));
    if (negative) a = -a;

    // skip spaces
    while (ch != EOF && isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') ch = getchar();

    // read operator
    if (ch == EOF || (ch != '+' && ch != '-' && ...)) {
        // error, expecting an operator
    }
    op = ch;
    ch = getchar();
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help through all of this. I'm trying my best to do this on my own, but at the moment, my code does not work with no spaces, or more than one space. I tried to implement a few things from your code, but didn't get it completely working yet.

Comment: I put together a working version [here](http://pastebin.com/guykHSRQ).  It will expire in 2 weeks.  Make sure you understand what it's doing.